# Docstring format for input numpy arrays with mandatory datatype and dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

For the sake of example, assume that I have a function that takes two numpy arrays as input parameters. The first array must be 2-dimensional and contain only floats. The second array must be 1-dimensional and contain only booleans.

Thus far I haven't really been able to find an existing convention for specifying input array datatype and dimensions in the docstring. One possible format (taking numpy docstring conventions as a basis) that I thought of was this:

```
def example_function(arr1, arr2):
    """This is an example function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    arr1 : ndarray(dtype=float, ndim=2)
        Array containing some kind of data.
    arr2 : ndarray(dtype=bool, ndim=1)
        Array containing some kind of mask.

   """
```

Can this be considered a 'correct' docstring format? (i.e. does it not break any rules of existing docstring conventions?)

Comment: I like your suggestion more than the accepted answer, it is more concise and the information would always be at the same place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dimension and item types are extra information about your arrays which are function arguments. Thus based on documentation you need a style like follows:

```
"""
x : type
    Description of parameter `x`.
"""
```

Which in this case should be like:

```
"""
Parameters
----------
arr1 : ndarray
    2D array containing data with `float` type.
arr2 : ndarray
    1D mask array(containing data with boolean type).
"""
```

And note that if you want to make more clarifications you better to describe the data types and dimensions in your function description part as well.

Comment: Should line 6 in your answer then be `arr2 : ndarray`?